# Load testing using loadrunner in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a project requirement to do load testing using loadrunner in AWS.
Can anyone provide a detailed test approach how to do this and what are the pre-requisites to start as this is very new to us.

Comment: Please define the "very new" context.  Is this new to LoadRunner?  New to AWS?  New to testing of applications in AWS with LoadRunner?  New to hosting load in AWS with LoadRunner?  Each of these paths takes you to a different set of answers

Comment: Its- New to testing of applications in AWS with LoadRunner.The project team is going to use AWS to setup the performance test environment. Wanted to know the performance testing approach followed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be concerned with Load Generators running under virtualized environments.  There are a number of reasons for this, but first among them is the virtualized system clock which is loosely coupled to the physical system clock.  Periodically the floating (degrading) virtual clock will need to be resynchronized with the physical system clock and this leads to a clock jump on the resync.  This leads to higher recorded averages, percentiles, maximums on your response times as inevitably this happens when a timing record is open.  This is tool independent.  This floating system clock issue will also impact your controller (reporting clock integrity) and your SiteScope instance (monitoring interval) should you choose to install any of those components in the cloud.
2. You lose control over your initial and in-test conditions on a shared load generator running in a virtual machine.  From one test to the next you will be unable to control what the other machines are doing on the same host and whether you have any arbitrated access to a resource (CPU, DISK, MEMORY, NETWORK) which will degrade the users running on your hosts.
3. You will need a physical host as a reference control factor someplace.  Think of this as a high confidence/high precision clock host employing statistical sampling (5% of your samples) to add a degree of confidence to your result set.  It would be best to have this in a location which is a representative one for your users of the application
4. Having your load generators in the same location (AWS) as your application under test results in an unnatural network traversal condition which will show as abnormally short response times to an actual user with a much more complex network to traverse versus within the same data center (potentially). This makes the control/reference generator that much more critical when you combine this with clock jump
5. You don't pay for in-data center network traffic between hosts at AWS, but you do pay for network bytes into and out of the cloud.  So, inside of AWS load generators reduce your per test direct costs for network fees, but at the cost of reduced integrity of the result set
6. The latest version of LoadRunner is integrated with Amazon accounts to allow you to use load generators in the cloud. As is StormRunner, the cloud hosted version of LoadRunner technology from HP.   Just make sure you shut down your load generator instances at the end of tests instead of leaving them running.  This last item is not tool specific as many tools are great at spinning up instances for generating load, but not so great at shutting them down.
7. **Read your license agreement very carefully as this may govern where you install components.** In particular you will want to read the provisions associated with remote access to a controller and where the application is tested related to the location of the components.   You will want to go over this agreement with the PM and the team proposing where components are installed just to ensure that all of the "i"s are dotted and the "t"s are crossed in case you face a software audit at any point. You do not want surprises at the end of such an event.